# hdfs data skew, why the files are not evenly distributed?

Tags: hadoop

I run a HDFS with 32 slaves.

Each slave have roughly 300GB local disk space remaining (the rest are not for HDFS.)

When I put 32 * 100 GB files, the files are delivered to only some slaves. It crashes the task due to the out of disk space.

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an admin but here is the first thing that popped in my head when looking at your question.

Hadoop is a "topology aware" system. Please read about it
[here.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html)

If the topology is not correct then the HDFS writes with default replication (3x) will write in order (random node --> node on a different rack --> same rack as 2nd replica but a different node).

Good idea to check the replication factor also. Hope this helps!